# background-size not getting scaled after cover

Tags: android, html, css

this would be my 1st question here which tells am new at programming.

I have a background image which just isn't getting scaled after using 'background-size :cover' or background-size: 100% 100%;

This problem only seems to occur only on android devices

Min- width and min-height doesn't work and I have encountered several ppl with similar problems but their solutions have not helped

This is my css

```
body {

        background-image: url("../img/bck-img.png");
        background-color: transparent !important;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
        -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
        -o-background-size:100% 100%;
        background-attachment:fixed ;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        /*
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size:cover;
        background-attachment:fixed ;
        */
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        min-height:100%;
        width:100%;
        }   

html{  /*height:100%;*/ min-height:100%; width: 100%;}


#nav1 {
width: 100%;
height:35%;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
position:fixed;
left:0px;
top:0px;}
```

The comments are different trial and error soultions
Thanks

Comment: The Android device you're testing on probably doesn't support `background-size`

Comment: All android devices i've tested shows the same